# Prioritize more specific selection

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have the following html:

```
<div className="a">
  <div className="b">
    <h1>text</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

as well as the following css:

```
.a h1 {
  properies...
}

.b h1 {
  properties...
}
```

The `h1` is selected by both selectors since it is a descendant of both `a` and `b`. Surprisingly to me, the `h1` is taking its properties from `.a h1` as opposed to `.b h1`.

In fact, in the Chrome console, the properties in the second selectors are strikethrough-ed.

Why does the first selector "win" and how can I make the second one override the first one?

Comment: *Surprisingly to me, the h1 is taking its properties from .a h1 as opposed to .b h1* --> we need to see

Comment: This looks like `jsx` not plain `html`. If you replace `className` with `class` it works as expected.

Comment: And if it is `jsx` you would need to check how that `css` is being handled... css-in-js, styled-components...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The furthest parent takes always priority over the closer (it does not matter the order in your `css` sheet). for example `body h1` would take priority over `.a h1`.

The same way, snipping an element trhough `#id` would take priority over `.class` ignoring the order in the `css sheet`

```
<div id="ida" className="a">
  <div className="b">
    <h1>text</h1>
  </div>
</div> 

#ida h1 {color:red;}
.a h1 {color:green;}
```

The color will be always red.

This is very usefull to avoid using `important!` in your `css`.

https://htmldog.com/guides/css/intermediate/specificity/